# AWS S3 Folder - recursive access

Tags: recursion, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4

In My Project, I have S3 bucket but i have to recursively acccess all the objects within that given bucket. It should be like recursively processing directory or file structure. When i tried to access the objects of the bucket, I'm getting AccessDeniedException.

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['bucket_name']
bucket.objects #raises Exception
```

Comment: Are you the same user the creator of the bucket and the files inside it?

Comment: Yes, I'm the creater of files and subfolders in it. but i'm not the one who created the root folder @RatanSharma

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but I had a problem where I was not able to upload to anything other than the root folders with the other IAM accounts I created. After adding this change in the image below I was able to put objects in folders other than the root path.

In my case I had created the bucket with the root account, but had another user that was setup to add files to the bucket. The other user account was the one that had issues adding new items into the bucket.

[image]